# facebook graph api me/friends missing results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph v1 api me/friends but in some case the result is incomplete!

For example:

- user u1 has 616 friends but only 13 are returned.
- u2 has 547 friends but only 17 are returned.
- u3 has 580 friends and all 580 friends are returned.

The tokens that I used are valid and if I use a FQL query the results are the same.

How can I fetch all friends of u1 and u2??

Thanks in advance

Comment: If suspect Users u1 and u2 access tokens were acquired using a v2.0 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you are using graph v1. However, the [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/friends)  says:

> Once a user has logged into an app using version 2.0 (or later), calling this edge for v1.0 will continue to return the later version's response.

Perhaps now you are getting the later version's response, and [version 2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends) says:

> This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.

Maybe only 13 friends of u1 have used the app, and only 17 friends of u2 have used the app.

Comment: If u1 and u2 wouldn't use the app, there wouldn't be anything returned for them. I doubt that the access tokens were generated with the same app, or at least same Graph API version

Comment: I mean that only 13 friends of u1 used the app, and only 17 friends of u2 have used the app. I agree with your comment, I think is a version problem. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Yes the tokens are generated with the same app and all facebook end point are unversioned.
Maybe the last users logged using v.2.0?? How can I force to log with 1.0 version?

Comment: I investigated and I found out there is an iOs app that use v2.0 
So in my app there are some users logged using versione 2.0 :(